# Django: join string on a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a template filter to show who liked a post. Each comment contains a ManyToManyField with the users who upvoted a post. I am trying to use the join method to simplify my code instead of using a for loop. This does not work and I get the error ManyToManyField is not iterable.

```
 #post.html
    ...
    <span class="tooltip_text">{{ comment.user_upvotes.all|format_upvote_users }}</span>
    ...

#template_filters.py
@register.filter
def format_upvote_users(queryset):
    # This works:
    upvoters = ''
    for user in queryset:
        upvoters += ', ' + user
    # This doesn't:
    upvoters = ','.join(user in queryset)
    ...
    return upvoters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do that like:

```
upvoters = ','.join(user for user in queryset)
```

See ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions))

Comment: Works, will accept when stack allows. Any quick explanation for why this works without scanning the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

upvote = [ user.link for user in queryset ]